# Restrict decimal and allowing only number

Tags: javascript, html, validation, decimal

I am trying validate text field which will allow only number by restricting decimal but due to some reason it is accepting decimal also.

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');"></input>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like:

*Javascript is required

Will only allow numbers and back space keys

```html
<input type="text" onkeypress="return (event.charCode !=8 && event.charCode ==0 || (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57))" />
```

Answer (score 0):

check now

```html
<input type="text" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')" />
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `toUpperCase()` here?

Answer (score 0):

Your original solution was close - the 2nd `replace` isn't necessary if you just remove `.` from the negated match in the first `replace`:

```
<input type="text" id="textbox" maxlength="10" oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');"></input>
```